# How to select a different event for an asp.net control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I actually don't know how to find the other events for an ASP.NET control. How do I find the events such as `onDoubleClick`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on Properties for the control. Below the drop-down menu, you should see several buttons. Click on the lightning bolt icon and you will see a list of different events associated with that control.

Comment: So it was right in front of me the whole time! Thankyou very much!